# Is setting the width and height of an SVG important for indexing?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, images, svg, image-size

Generally, when SVGs are displayed responsively, we only need to set the `viewBox` attribute on the `<svg>` and can entirely omit the `width` and `height` attributes (i.e. something like `<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">` is enough). So, I wonder how SVG images with `width` and `height` attributes omitted are indexed by a search engine like Google, i.e. with what size they are displayed in Image Search.

I did a little bit of searching, and it seems that they are displayed as follows:

- if the graphic is wider than tall: width is `800px` and height is set to preserve the aspect ratio
- else: height is `800px` and width is set to preserve the aspect ratio

On the other hand, SVG images with `width` and `height` attributes set seem to be displayed in Image Search with the size as indicated in the two attributes (e.g. `<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="100" height="100">` is displayed as `100x100`).

I also found an SVG image whose `width` and `height` are set to `100%` , and it is displayed as `2000x2000` in Image Search.

So, what is the best practice for the `width` and `height` attributes of SVG images? Should they be omitted, set to `100%`, or set to some other value?

Answer (score 5):

While SVG's can be a purpose of their own, websites, accessibility readers and much of what you need to account for with SEO, is based on the standard IMG schema.

Because of this, it's best practice to do what search engines expect, which is to use the established good old IMG schema and all its attributes.

As SVG matures, no doubt we will see more robust image schemas develop, but for now, keep with the regular IMG schema that accessibility devices and all browsers understand.

---

### Based on the above

Always define the width and height attributes of an image. This will help avoid unnecessary repaints and reflows during rendering.

---

### Google Page Speed

[image]

If you don't markup code correctly using HTML height and width properties and it has an impact on your site, [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and other search engines will penalise you in search results.

[image]

---

### Media Embedding

Furthermore, your images may not display correctly when [embedding](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html) in applications or social media.

---

[HTML  width & Height Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp)

> Always specify both the height and width attributes for images. If
>   height and width are set, the space required for the image is reserved
>   when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes, the
>   browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the
>   appropriate space to it. The effect will be that the page layout will
>   change during loading (while the images load).

[Sitespeed: Do images require width and height attributes?](https://moz.com/community/q/sitespeed-do-images-require-width-and-height-attributes)

> When you include the image dimensions, the browser can draw out the
>   "containers" that will hold the images, reserving the space for them
>   while they download. The browser can then go on the paint the rest of
>   the pages CSS and objects around those "containers" without having to
>   go back and redraw the whole page once the images have downloaded and
>   their sizes are then known.

---

See [technical specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/respimg-usecases/) on  W3C.

Comment: Setting `width` and `height` on `<img>` to avoid the weird jumping of content worked back in the day when responsive design did not exist. But today, to have a container for an image before it loads, a div is used which has `height:0` and `padding-top` set to have the correct aspect ratio, and the image is then absolutely positioned within that div. This makes the container of the image responsive, rather than fixed size. Also, please add links to official pages to back up your statement about being penalized if not setting `width/height` on `<img>`.

Comment: By the way, in the question I am not talking about the `width/height` attributes of `<img>` but the `width/height` attributes of `<svg>` (which is within the SVG file referenced by `<img>`)

Comment: The Google Page Speed link I provided has a lot of info within. I will provide more details tomorrow. It’s 3am here, so probably not the best time to do anything detailed. As for the SVG, it’s the same mechanism. The browser needs to know what sizes to render the item. SVG is vector whereas IMG is rasta. I’ll explain more tomorrow. Good night :)

Comment: If you have a JPEG image, it has a specific width and height, and when indexed it will have that width and height. However, an SVG can have its width and height set to any value or completely omitted. So the question is about whether to set `width/height` on `<svg>` to some specific value or completely omit them. The question has nothing to do with `width/height` attributes of `<img>`. To better clarify what I mean: even if I set `width/height` on the `<svg>`, the browser will not know the size until it downloaded the SVG file.

Comment: 4:20am and Im still awake :( Anyway, another reason it’s can harm SEO if you’re not using img schemas, is accessibility. Take a look a this Google Developers page. They clearly use the height and width attributes in their schema and for good reasons. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images#use_svg_for_icons

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Also. I feel this is a very good question and one that's hard to answer fully. So if anyone has more to add, it will be really good in this forever changing environment of crazy web crazyness!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with when it comes to setting or not setting the `width/height` attributes on the `<svg>` element (which is inside the `.svg` file and has nothing to do with `width/height` of the `<img>` element whose `src` is set to that `.svg` file, just to be clear).

Not setting `width/height` attributes on the `<svg>` element seems to be the best choice if your SVG is responsive because: 1) when a user opens that SVG in a separate tab, the SVG will fill the entire screen, rather than being of fixed size and thus often being displayed either too small, or too big (and thus causing scrollbars to appear); 2) When a search engine accesses the SVG file, it does not see a `width` and `height` specified on the `<svg>` element, and thus that SVG is probably interpreted as a responsive SVG, thus the search engine chooses what's the best size to display it in Image Search (which currently seems to be `800px`, at least for Google, but this may change in the future); 3) when such an SVG is included with `<img>`, and the `<img>` does not specify `width/height` attributes, then `<img>` will simply fill the entire available width. However, you are free to specify `width/height` on the `<img>` to any value you want, and it will be properly sized.

The only case I can think of when setting `width/height` on the `<svg>` might be useful is when that SVG is always supposed to be shown with that specific size, no matter what the screen size is (in other words, the SVG is not supposed to be responsive). Setting `width/height` will ensure that when a user opens the SVG in a separate tab, it will have the size you specified, search engines will index it with the size you specified, and when such an SVG is included with `<img>`, and the `<img>` does not specify `width/height` attributes, then the size of `<img>` will match the `width/height` specified in `<svg>`. However, if you specify `width/height` attributes on the `<img>`, and they don't match the ones specified on `<svg>`, the SVG will be properly resized to the size indicated in `<img>`, but since the SVG is supposed to have fixed size, if you decide to set `width/height` attributes on `<img>`, you probably want to set them to match the `width/height` attributes of `<svg>`.